Can you checkmate a king you can't see?
Motivation
If you play bullet chess with time management skills as poor as mine, you often end up in endgame situations that require delivering checkmate by playing several premoves in a row. For example, a useful technique in these situations is the ladder mate shown below.

In the diagram above, the black king is invisible, but no matter where it starts or how it moves, checkmate is guaranteed.
Game
Setup
Alice has a standard set of eight white chess pieces excluding pawns: one king, one queen, two rooks, two knights, and two bishops. Bob has a lone black king. The players start with three chessboards.
Gameplay

Alice places all her pieces except the king anywhere on the three boards.
Bob chooses a board, discarding the other two.
Alice places her king anywhere on the board.
Alice wears a blindfold to prevent her from seeing Bob's king.
Bob places his king on any safe square. (If he can't, Alice wins.)
Alice announces her move to Bob. If it's illegal, Bob wins.
Bob plays Alice's legal move. If it results in checkmate, Alice wins, and if stalemate, Bob wins.
Bob makes a legal move with his king without revealing it to Alice.
The players repeat steps 6 through 8 until a player wins as stated or the fifty-move rule applies, in which case Bob wins.

In summary, Alice wins by checkmate (or if Bob can't place his king), and Bob wins through an illegal move by Alice, stalemate, or the fifty-move rule.
Question
Does Alice have a strategy to always win no matter how Bob plays?
Visualizer
I wrote a simple tool to help visualize the problem.
Setup
To set up a position, you can drag pieces around or off the board to remove them, then start the game by pressing F or the start button in the 3 dots menu. Alternatively, you can use the PGN button to paste and import a PGN.
Gameplay
After a game is started, black kings will be placed at every position the black king could be located. After you play a move, the black kings will automatically move to the new possible locations, unless the game ends by checkmate, stalemate, or piece capture, which will be indicated by arrows. (Ending the game when a piece is captured is a limitation of the visualizer.)
During a game, the menu has four buttons:

Reset: return to setup mode (also by pressing F)
Analysis Board: open chess.com using the current PGN
Link: generate a URL for the current PGN
PGN: view the PGN of the current position.

For example, here is the ladder mate example from earlier. You can play through the moves with the arrow buttons or arrow keys.

Feel free to use this if you find it helpful. And please let me know if you have any questions or run into any issues. Have fun! :-)

If Bob's move captures one of Alice's pieces, is that revealed to her? If not, is making a move with that piece now illegal?

@StephenTG No, not revealed, and yes, illegal.

That 50-move-rule sure is annoying ...

Great puzzle idea! Can't wait to get home and try some ideas. Laptop > phone

The app is so cool, but I do wish you could keep going beyond 50 moves just to see if it possible to finish off a position, even if it doesn't count for the solution to the puzzle.

@TylerSeacrest Thanks for trying it out! I modeled the behavior of ending the game past the 50-move rule after Lichess' own analysis board, but I agree that it's a needlessly annoying limitation. I've now changed it so that you can keep playing moves past 50, but they'll be displayed in red as a warning indicator. (Although you might not see the move list in mobile portrait mode, another limitation of the app.) Thanks for the feedback!

Nice visualization! So the idea is to divide the 7 pieces into three disjoint configurations, each with a white king, and we should be able to win each of them using the rules. Sounds really interesting!

Wow, thanks for introducing me to Can all 64 squares be attacked or defended by the eight pieces?

@BenjaminWang That question requires that the squares the pieces occupy are attacked by other pieces.


 Alice wins,

as was already shown by the combination of Tim Seifert's partial solution and Albert.Lang's squeeze.  If one further takes into account noedne's comment, then that solution takes a combined

 17+33+50 = 100 moves.

This answer offers an improvement of

 10 moves to now have a combined 13+28+49 = 90 moves.

Furthermore, each individual board is improved so this offers a worst-case improvement as well,

 strictly below the 50-move threshold which Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine wondered about.

The solution is as follows:

 On the first board, Alice places two rooks and then performs a

very efficient "ladder mate"

 in 13 moves (an improvement of 4 moves).  Her strategy is to start the rooks in the corner similar to previous approaches, but put the king closer to the center and then aggressively shrink the potential black king region.

Try it online! (visualization)

 On the second board, Alice places a knight and a queen and then dances them around checkmating black in 28 moves (an improvement of 5 moves).

Try it online! (visualization)

 On the third board, Alice places the remaining knight and one bishop of each tint.  And then finally she checkmates black in 49 moves (an improvement of 1 move).  Note that the first 21 moves differ in my link (because the solution was found independently), but may as well be the same because they accomplish the same thing.  They differ meaningfully from the 22nd move and also finish in different corners.

Try it online! (visualization)
For completeness, here are some PGNs you can copy-paste:

 [FEN "8/8/8/8/3K4/5k2/R7/1R6"]
 1. Rb3+ Kg4 2. Ra6 Kf4 3. Kd5 Kg4 4. Ra7 Kf4 5. Kd6 Ke4 6. Ra4+ Kf5 7. Rb5+ Kf6 8. Ra8 Kg6 9. Kd7 Kf6 10. Ra6+ Kg7 11. Re5 Kf7 12. Re7+ Kf8 13. Ra8# 1-0 
 [FEN "8/8/8/k7/8/3N4/1Q2K3/8"]
 1. Qb4 Ka6 2. Qc5 Kb7 3. Qe5 Ka6 4. Ne1 Kb6 5. Nf3 Ka6 6. Ng5 Kb6 7. Ne4 Ka6 8. Qg5 Kb6 9. Kf2 Ka6 10. Qh5 Kb6 11. Ke3 Ka6 12. Kd4 Kb6 13. Kc3 Ka6 14. Qg5 Kb6 15. Kb4 Ka6 16. Qf6 Ka7 17. Nc3 Kb7 18. Ne2 Ka7 19. Ng3 Kb7 20. Nf5 Ka7 21. Qg7 Kb6 22. Ne3 Ka6 23. Qf6 Ka7 24. Nd5 Kb7 25. Kb5 Ka7 26. Qe7 Kb8 27. Ka6 Ka8 28. Qe8# 1-0 
 [FEN "8/8/8/1B6/8/2B5/1K6/2N3k1"]
 1. Be2 Kh1 2. Kc2 Kg1 3. Kd1 Kh1 4. Nb3 Kg1 5. Bd4 Kh1 6. Kd2 Kg2 7. Kc3 Kh1 8. Kb4 Kg2 9. Ka5 Kh1 10. Bb6 Kg2 11. Nd2 Kh1 12. Bf3 Kh2 13. Ka6 Kg3 14. Ba7 Kh2 15. Bb7 Kg3 16. Nc4 Kh2 17. Na3 Kg3 18. Nb5 Kh2 19. Bb6 Kg3 20. Na7 Kh2 21. Bc6 Kg3 22. Kb7 Kh2 23. Nb5 Kg3 24. Kc7 Kh2 25. Bc5 Kg3 26. Nc3 Kh2 27. Ne2 Kh3 28. Bd6 Kg4 29. Nd4 Kh3 30. Kd7 Kg4 31. Bd5 Kh3 32. Nc2 Kg4 33. Ne3 Kh3 34. Be6 Kh4 35. Nd5 Kg5 36. Ke7 Kh4 37. Be5 Kg5 38. Ne3 Kh4 39. Ng2 Kg5 40. Bf6 Kh5 41. Nf4 Kh6 42. Bf7 Kh7 43. Ne6 Kh6 44. Bg5 Kh7 45. Nf8 Kg7 46. Bf6 Kh6 47. Bh4 Kg7 48. Bg5 Kh8 49. Bf6# 1-0

Bonus!:

 Obviously a rook and queen can checkmate easily in 6 moves, but also a bishop and queen can checkmate in 19 moves.


Awesome work! I tried writing some code to search for solutions and managed to solve the third board in 47 moves!

This is also just a partial solution:

 Alice

can win as long as the players agree to use the

 slightly more generous 51-move rule.

Play on the three boards will go like this:
The first board contains

 two rooks, which make it straightforward to carry out the usual ladder mate - just make sure that the king always defends the vulnerable rook. Just for completeness, here is a winning line in 17 moves (exported from noedne's excellent tool):


 [FEN "8/8/8/8/8/3k4/R7/KR6"] [Result "1-0"]  1. Rbb2 Kc3 2. Ra3 Kc4 3. Ka2 Kd4 4. Rbb3 Kc4 5. Ra4 Kc5 6. Ka3 Kd5 7. Rbb4 Kc5 8. Ra5 Kc6 9. Ka4 Kd6 10. Rbb5 Kc6 11. Ra6 Kc7 12. Ka5 Kd7 13. Rbb6 Kc7 14. Ra7 Kc8 15. Ka6 Kd8 16. Rbb7 Kc8 17. Ra8# 1-0

The second board contains

 the queen and a knight. This is already a bit tricky, mostly because the queen is really good at stalemating. But with a bit of fiddling, I came up with a straightforward method to make reliable progress here. The essential idea is to push the black king(s) upward by blocking most of the topmost free row with the king and the knight and then advancing the queen forward. Setting this up right, this lets only a single king slip which can be mated the next turn without losing progress. With a bit of optimization, this can surely be done faster, but here is one way to do it in 45 moves:


 [FEN "8/8/8/8/8/k7/2Q5/N4K2"] [Result "1-0"] 1. Qg2 Ka4 2. Qc2 Ka5 3. Qb3 Ka6 4. Kf2 Ka5 5. Qc2 Kb4 6. Qb3 Ka5 7. Nc2 Ka6 8. Qb4 Ka7 9. Ne1 Ka6 10. Ng2 Ka7 11. Nf4 Ka6 12. Ne2 Ka7 13. Kf3 Ka6 14. Qg4 Ka5 15. Qh4 Kb5 16. Kg3 Ka5 17. Nc1 Kb5 18. Nd3 Ka5 19. Qb4 Ka6 20. Qc5 Kb7 21. Nf2 Ka6 22. Kg4 Kb7 23. Nd1 Ka6 24. Ne3 Kb7 25. Nc2 Ka6 26. Nd4 Kb7 27. Qb5 Ka8 28. Qc6 Ka7 29. Nf3 Kb8 30. Kf5 Ka7 31. Nd2 Kb8 32. Nb3 Ka7 33. Nc5 Kb8 34. Qa6 Kc7 35. Qb7 Kd8 36. Ne4 Ke8 37. Ng5 Kd8 38. Kf4 Ke8 39. Qh7 Kd8 40. Qf7 Kc8 41. Ke5 Kb8 42. Kd6 Ka8 43. Kc6 Kb8 44. Qd7 Ka8 45. Qb7# 1-0

Now, the third board is the proper challenge, containing

 both bishops and a knight. This is made difficult by the simple fact that the simple ladder mate does not work on diagonals. Two bishops can form a barrier but are unable to make progress by themselves. Moreover, safe maneuvering is very clumsy since the bishops cannot defend themselves and the knight can only defend one at a time. With all that going against us, it is perhaps surprising that this can be done at all - the overall approach being the insight that a ladder-type mate can work by advancing three diagonals up the board. This works by positioning the king and knight around so as to double block the current frontier and only then advancing a bishop forward. Since a knight can only block up to four squares on a diagonal this way, we run into a bit of trouble on the long diagonals, where the king has to lift more weight, while simultaneously defending the bishops at the same time. All these maneuvers eat up a lot of time, and the final mate is also a bit awkward, since we can only attack squares of a single colour every turn (so it is very easy to produce a stalemate near the end). Nonetheless, I was able to whittle this down to 51 (!) moves (which is frustratingly close to a full solution):


 [FEN "8/8/8/8/8/N7/1K1BB3/6k1"] [Result "1-0"] 1. Bb5 Kh1 2. Kb3 Kg1 3. Ka4 Kh1 4. Nc2 Kg1 5. Be3 Kh1 6. Ka5 Kg2 7. Bb6 Kh1 8. Na1 Kg2 9. Nb3 Kh1 10. Nd2 Kg2 11. Bd3 Kh1 12. Be4 Kh2 13. Ka6 Kg3 14. Ba7 Kh2 15. Bb7 Kg3 16. Nb1 Kh2 17. Na3 Kg3 18. Nb5 Kh2 19. Bc5 Kg3 20. Kb6 Kh2 21. Nc3 Kg3 22. Ne2 Kh2 23. Be3 Kh3 24. Bf4 Kg4 25. Bc7 Kh3 26. Nd4 Kg4 27. Nc2 Kh3 28. Ne3 Kh4 29. Be4 Kh3 30. Bf5 Kh4 31. Kc6 Kg5 32. Bd7 Kh4 33. Nd5 Kg5 34. Nc3 Kh4 35. Ne4 Kh5 36. Be5 Kh4 37. Bf6 Kh5 38. Kd6 Kg6 39. Be7 Kh5 40. Ng3 Kh6 41. Bg4 Kg6 42. Bh5 Kg7 43. Ke6 Kh6 44. Bf7 Kg7 45. Nf5 Kh8 46. Kf6 Kh7 47. Bf8 Kh8 48. Bd5 Kh7 49. Be4 Kg8 50. Bg7 Kh7 51. Ne7# 1-0

Try as I might, I was not able to get this down any more than that. Maybe someone else will have an idea of how to get it done (perhaps using another approach)?

That's so frustratingly close, and yet it's so optimized!

Here's a link to visualize your first mate, generated using the Link menu button.

And here's a 33-mover combining ideas from your second and Retudin's mates.

Wow! Forcing a mate with only minor pieces is not trivial even if you can see the opponent's king!

@Tim Seifert has done most of the work. Starting from Tim's KBBN vs k I managed to squeeze out the last excess move. The idea is to switch to the other (orthogonal) diagonals (which are more but shorter) half-way through:
[FEN "8/8/8/8/3N4/2B5/1K6/3B2k1"]
[Result "1-0"]

Be2 Kh1 2. Kc2 Kg1 3. Kd1 Kh1 4. Nb3 Kg1 5. Bd4 Kg2 6. Kc2 Kh1 7. Kc3 Kg2 8. Kb4 Kh1 9. Ka5 Kg2 10. Bb6 Kh1 11. Nd2 Kg2 12. Bf3 Kg3 13. Ka6 Kh2 14. Ba7 Kg3 15. Bb7 Kh2 16. Nc4 Kg3 17. Na3 Kh2 18. Nb5 Kg3 19. Bb6 Kh2 20. Na7 Kg3 21. Bc6 Kh2 22. Kb5 Kg3 23. Nc8 Kh2 24. Bc5 Kg3 25. Nd6 Kh2 26. Nb7 Kg3 27. Nd8 Kh2 28. Kc4 Kg3 29. Bd5 Kh2 30. Nc6 Kg3 31. Nb8 Kh2 32. Nd7 Kg3 33. Bd4 Kh2 34. Nf8 Kg3 35. Kd3 Kh2 36. Be4 Kg3 37. Ne6 Kh2 38. Be3 Kg3 39. Ng7 Kh2 40. Ke2 Kg3 41. Bf3 Kh2 42. Nf5 Kh3 43. Kf2 Kh2 44. Be2 Kh1 45. Kf3 Kh2 46. Bf1 Kh1 47. Bf4 Kg1 48. Ng3 Kh2 49. Bg2 Kg1 50. Ne2# 1-0

(paste this into OP's lovely tool to replay)

Nicely done! It's interesting to see how this beats the more straightforward attempt by apparantly doing more work. These long knight maneuvers in the longer solution really do accumulate

Here's the visualization, generated with the Link button.

And here's a similar 50-mover using different maneuvers.

Who gets the check mark? ;) @noedne

@noedne oo, the ending of the alternative solution is interesting

I'm starting to see why the puzzle uses a peculiar way to set up the pieces. Since it might be impossible when starting from a general position (assuming Black can't immediately win material).

I wonder if it’s possible to squeeze it any shorter!  If 50 really is the minimum sufficient, that would be quite remarkable.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: It's possible to squeeze it at least one move shorter! https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/129184/63291

Partial answer:

 Alice can easily win with two rooks. (with a king-supported ladder mate).
 Alice can (barely) win with a queen + knight (see game below, with 'random' moves for black leading to the longest survival of black).
 Considering that, I cannot imagine Alice winning on the 3rd board (with only 3 lesser pieces, which Bob will choose). I have no prove though. Considering the question is asked, I assume I am missing something.
 [Variant "From Position"]
 [FEN "8/k7/8/6K1/5N2/8/6Q1/8 w - - 0 1"]
 1. Qe2 Kb6 2. Qe6+ Ka5 3. Ng6 Kb5 4. Qe7 Ka5 5. Nf4 Kb5 6. Kg6 Ka5 7. Qe8 Ka6 8. Kf7 Kb6 9. Qe7 Ka6 10. Ke8 Ka5 11. Qe6 Kb5 12. Nd5 Ka5 13. Kd7 Kb5 14. Nf6 Ka5 15. Ng4 Kb5 16. Qe5+ Ka6 17. Nh6 Kb6 18. Nf7 Ka7 19. Nd8 Ka6 20. Kc8 Kb6 21. Qe6+ Kb5 22. Kc7 Ka5 23. Nf7 Kb5 24. Ng5 Ka5 25. Qe4 Ka6 26. Ne6 Ka5 27. Nf8 Ka6 28. Ng6 Ka5 29. Ne7 Ka6 30. Nc8 Kb5 31. Qe6 Kc5 32. Kb7 Kb4 33. Nb6 Kc5 34. Nd7+ Kd4 35. Qe5+ Kc4 36. Kb6 Kb4 37. Nc5 Kc4 38. Qe4+ Kc3 39. Kb5 Kd2 40. Qd3+ Ke1 41. Qf3 Kd2 42. Kb4 Ke1 43. Kc4 Kd2 44. Ne6 Kc2 45. Nf4 Kb2 46. Qe2+ Ka3 47. Nd3 Ka4 48. Qb2 Ka5 49. Qb5#


I'm fairly certain she can do it, but all my attempts so far exceed 50 moves

I was able to make moderate progress with K+B+B+N in 50 moves. It's probably possible, I just haven't found it yet

I can currently do it in 62, so pretty close. It's probably possible
